# why my second function is not working jquery click method?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(()=>{     
      $('#perform').click(function(){//when clicked it changes text of button to 
                                      show from hide    
          $('#perform').text('Show')        
           $('#message').hide()   //hides the text      
       }, function(){            
            $('#perform').text('Hide')           
            $('#message').show()       
      }); 
  });
```

The ID `#perform` is a button and the ID `#message` is for a div.
Why is my second function not working?

When the button is clicked it hides the div and changes the `#message` to show. When we click on `show` thaen it displays the `div`

Comment: Please include the HTML with your elements in it so that we can see your entire code to better help.

Comment: `toggle` is an option for you

Comment: Refer to the `toggle` function in jQuery here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure: Using `toggle()` is the better solution. But to answer your question:

Looks like you're passing two parameters to the "set click() event" function. According to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/) this gets interpreted as `.click( [eventData ], handler )` -> Your second function gets added as the handler.

If you REALLY wanted to force this to work you'd need to re-set the click() handler every time the element is clicked:

```
function hideMessage(){
  $('#perform').text('Show');        
  $('#message').hide();   //hides the text
  $('#perform').click(showMessage);
}

function showMessage(){            
  $('#perform').text('Hide');
  $('#message').show();
  $('#perform').click(hideMessage);
}

$(document).ready(()=>{     
  $('#perform').click(hideMessage); 
});
```

Tested in [this JSFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/mqrMk/6422/)

Comment: Its not working  when i clicked on hide button no action is performed

Comment: You still need to show us some HTML. Then I can edit my answer.

Comment: <button id="perform" href="#">Hide</button>
  <div id="message" style="width: 30vw; border: 1px solid orange; padding: 20px;"">
  The Pessimist Sees Difficulty In Every Opportunity. The Optimist Sees Opportunity In Every Difficulty.
  </div>

Comment: Please add it to your question.

Comment: Also, my answer was mostly to help you understand what was wrong with your `.click()` handler. You can really make this in a simpler way using `.toggle()` (it does have a bit more of a learning curve) and it'll help you more in later projects.

Comment: I agree with Vincent in an effort to better your code you should try out `.toggle()` and see if you cannot implement it in your code. Vincent's point is that you can achieve more with less effort by using the `.toggle()` method in jQuery and accomplish what you want.